# Get font colour of a cell in excel sheet in java

Tags: java, apache-poi

I want to get a Excel cell's color using Java and using Apache POI 3.11. I've tried the following:

```
if (cell.getCellStyle().getFillForegroundColor() == HSSFColor.RED.index) {
}
```

In the above chunk of code, the left side expression only returns 64, and I'm not sure why.

I also tried this:

```
Color color = cell.getCellStyle().getFillForegroundColorColor();

if (color != null) {
    if (color instanceof XSSFColor) {
        System.out.println("color is: " + ((XSSFColor) color).getARGBHex());
    } else if (color instanceof HSSFColor) {
        if ((color instanceof HSSFColor.AUTOMATIC))
            System.out.println("color is: " + ((HSSFColor) color).getHexString());
    }
}
```

However, that doesn't work either.

How would I accomplish this?

Comment: So the left side expression is an instance of ``Color`` (which the second snippet reveals)? Then it can't be "64 only".

Comment: Side note: instanceof is null safe

Comment: it didn't help!

Answer (score 0):

For HSSF (excel 97) format, font styles are stored grouped in workbook in an array. To get font color of a cell, check the cell style for index of the applied font from array, then get the font by index from workbook font array, and finally check the color of used font.

Also, HSSFColor is depracated so use IndexedColors.

```
HSSFWorkbook workbook;
Cell cell;
// TODO initialize workbook & cell properly

short fontIndex = cell.getCellStyle().getFontIndex();
Font font = workbook.getFontAt(fontIndex);
short fontColor = font.getColor();
if (fontColor != IndexedColors.RED.index) {
    // it's not red!!
}

// or in one line
short fontColor = workbook.getFontAt(cell.getCellStyle().getFontIndex()).getColor();
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code could solve the problem, it is best to add elaboration and explain how it works for people who might not understand this piece of code.

Comment: what is not clear to you?
as comment says, you have to initialize workbook & cell, which is case dependent and after that it is self-explanatory.

Comment: Graziani, code only answer are frowned upon because there is no clear explanation of why what you are doing solves the problem. There will be others who find this post on a problem related down the road and having a clear explanation is preferred. Remember stack overflow serves as a repository for good quality questions and answer.

Comment: The question was about styles, not fonts. So, the code is useless.